# leave light trail on path behind particles

Tags: particles

I am trying to create an effect where a particle emitter moves around a path and leaves the path glowing I have the particles working and have tried a couple of solutions to generate the lit path, but neither are ideal.

Solution One

Add a second emitter to my spark emitter that has zero gravity and zero initial speed. This works, but the particles have to be large in size and numbers otherwise gaps appear along the path.

Solution Two

Give the curve a bevel and use the build modifier to match the frames taken by the emitter to complete its journey along the path. This would look much better, but the mesh that gets built up does not match the particle emitter position due to the way that build works.

I have tried searching for a tutorial on this sort of thing, but it's difficult to know exactly what to search for.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the build modifier on a curve (with some bevel applied on using the object data properties) if you wanna do something like that:

[image]

Comment: Sanbaldo, Thanks, but I tied that and because of the way it builds the mesh along the curve it doesn't stay in time with the particles. Also I am working with a poly path. I have now tried using an array modifier, but that looks weird along some of the lines. Looks fine with a bezier curve.